# How to code a CLR reference function for a C++ MFC dll function

Tags: c#, mfc, clr

I have a MFC dll in C++ that has a function that exists like this:

```
typedef struct _nameinfo
{
    CString firstname;
    CString lastname;
    int item;
}

__declexport(dllexport) void import_name(_nameinfo *name, int progline);
```

So how do I represent this in the reference class and pass the name data
in so the c++ sees the data right and the c# code around it does too.

Comment: You cannot call this function from C#, you must write a wrapper in the C++/CLI language so you can properly construct the CString objects.

Comment: Ok I think I got it.